# How to direct the output of java program through HTML/CSS?

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to create an web application using java and java server pages .I want the **output of java file to display on jsp(web page)**..I am fairly new to jsp so don't know how to include a java program into a jsp file and output its variables...I have searched it but didn't found anything that could help me...any code or link to tutorial would be very helpful....
consider my filename is: **xyz.java** 
and I want to display value of **one of its variable**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I want to display value of one of its variable.

First of all if your class is not accessible in jsp than you need to import class

```
<%@ page import="com.my.YourClass" %>
```

Second you need to call method of class from which you want output or as you said you want to use value of variable but make sure it should be initialized you can directly use JSP Expression.

```
<%= new YourClass().variableName; %>
```

You can use this to directly display variable value to html page but make sure the variable should be accessible means should not be private.

You can use scriplet for that

FOR Example:

```
<%
System.out.println("Hello!!");
%>
```

Comment: if I want to print by using System.out.println(variablename) or ResultSetFormatter.out(variablename) then?

Answer (score 0):

```
I have searched it but didn't found anything that could help me
```

I highly doubt you couldnt find anything online

But here is your answer
If you want the variable in a JSP file import your java code

```
<%@ page import="com.xyz" %>
```

Next use that variable in jsp using scriplets like this

```
<%= new xyz.yourvariable; %>
```

So for example you want it in a label you can do this

```
<label><%= new xyz.yourvariable; %></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Step: Create 1 servlet file.

2 Step: write doGet method and assign the value into variable which you want to display in JSP

3 Step: set the variable into request scope using request.setAttribute() metnod

4 Step: redirect the servlet page to JSP page using RequestDispatcher class

5 Step: access the request scope variable into jsp page using <% %>

Test.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        req.setAttribute("msg", "Message");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("JSP Page Name").forward(req, resp);

        }
```

JSP Page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Message</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        out.println((String) request.getAttribute("msg"));
    %>
    </body>
</html>
```